# Correlation in a series of 1s and 0s

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, correlation

I have a series (in reality I have several series) of 1s and 0s (success and failures) and an "estimated" success-probability as well as the actual success-rate (I can count the 1s in my set).

I want to see if there is any correlation between if the previous outcome was a success and the success of the next outcome (also if the outcome have any affect on the outcome of the lets say next 3 outcomes).

I've tried asking multiple times here but it seems I am asking the wrong question because no one is answering me but instead tells me to "look at research" or that "I am just stupid".

Please, anyone have any ideas how I would go about finding any dependence between the outcomes?

Any ideas are welcome but no "This is a well studied subject please read this" as I have most likely all ready read it and still cant understand how to go about it.

Ive looked into auto-correlation but honestly cant grasp how to apply it to my problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: "I am just stupid" That's how you read the comments here? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708633/correlation-in-bernoulli-trial  "I have most likely already read it and still cant understand" This place is not for explaining such broad problems, that you can read in textbooks. Furthermore, asking the same question three times in a day does not help.

Comment: the "I am just stupid" was from me asking a similar question earlier and not your response:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707631/autocorrelation-test-for-bernoulli-distribution?noredirect=1#comment3484985_1707631

With that said I guess I though looking for patterns was an easier task that it is

Comment: To have " a serious and fundamental misunderstanding of probability theory" (which it seems you indeed have) has nothing to do with being stupid.

Comment: But thats what it sounds like when you ask someone for help and instead of helping you they simply point out that you dont know enough about the subject to be able to be helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it will help if we compare a sequence of 0's and 1's that is
not independent with another sequence that is.

**Dependent (weather model).** A Markov chain involves modeling one of the simplest kinds of dependence. Each value
can depend on the previous one, but knowing the previous value there
is no advantage in knowing earlier ones.

A simple example is an imaginary island where weather can be sunny (0)
or rainy (1) on any one day according to these rules: If it is
rainy today, it will be rainy tomorrow with probability .7. If it is sunny today, it will be sunny tomorrow with probability .7. One can
show that over the long run it is rainy on half of the days.

Here is a short R program that will generate such a random
sequence for 1000 days. Over our simulated 1000 days, we get
barely less than half rainy days, specifically 477,

```
 m = 1000;  x = numeric(m);  x[1] = 0
 for (i in 2:(m-1)) {
   if (x[i] == 0) {x[i+1] = rbinom(1, 1, .3)}
   else x[i+1] = rbinom(1, 1, .7)
 }
 mean(x)
 ##  0.477
```

The first plot below shows 0's and 1's for the first 20 days.
Notice the pattern: rainy days and sunny days tend to occur
is sequential 'clumps' of a few days, rather than alternating
independently. The second plot is an $autocorrelation\; function$ (ACF) plot for lags
up to 30. The ACF plot shows that once a rainy or sunny pattern
starts, it often takes a few days for the pattern to dissipate.

[image]

The ACF for 'order' or 'lag' $1$ is essentially the correlation
of the sequence $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{999}$ and the sequence
$X_2, X_3, \dots, X_{1000}$ This is not 'exactly' the correlation
of the two sequences because the sample means and SDs in the
correlation formula all use all 1000 observations instead of 999.
You should look for elementary discussions of 'autocorrelation'
online for more details.

The first autocorrelation in the plot is of order 0 (no lag).
It is always 1. (A correlation of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{1000}$
with itself.)

There is a test for when an autocorrelation of a particular lag
is significantly different from $0.$ The band marked with blue
dashed lines in the ACF plot indicate values that are consistent
with zero autocorrelation.

**Independent (coin tossing).** By contrast, here is corresponding output for
a sequence of independent coin tosses, with results Heads (1) and
Tails (0). Here the first plot shows changes independently and at random between values 0 and 1. Alternation between 0 and 1 tends
to be a little more rapid; but, of course, repeated values are
possible.

```
 x = rbinom(1000, 1, .5)
 mean(x)
 ## 0.507

 ## code for plot
 par(mfrow=c(1,2))  # enables two panels per plot
 plot(x[1:20], type="b", pch=20)  # "b" means Both points and lines
 acf(x)             # acf plot
 par(mfrow=c(1,1))  # return to single-panel plots
```

[image]

**Note:** There are a lot of concepts lurking in the questions you are
asking. I have tried to illustrate a few that may help get you
started. Please do not get discouraged by comments that seem
snarky to you. One step at a time, and you'll get the degree of understanding you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the uplifting words, having a bad day here...

But what I have problems with is the ACF (autocorrelation function). How is that defined?
My data-points are stored in an SQL-database and I would prefer to be able to work on them either programatically or in SQL (as in not export/import them to MathLab for example).

Comment: SQL is still on my list of many things to learn, so can't help you with that. Maybe check online to see if it does the equiv. of `ACF` in R.

Comment: ACF function just gives the autocorrelation for a sequence of lags. In R the number of lags displayed depends to an extent on the length of the input vector. (Can't have lag of order 15 for vector only 10 long!) But I believe R never shows beyond lag 40.

Comment: Ok, worst case scenario Im sure I can look up the definition of the ACF method in R.

You made my whole day my friend, if I could give you more upvotes I would  !